# Upload an Image via a Link

Tags: 7, media

When I create a new article in Drupal 7, there's a field to upload an image that will be associated with the article.  That image can only be uploaded directly from my computer.  Is there a way to make it so that Image fields will accept a link instead of a direct file upload?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [FileField Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) for this problem. It lets you use remote file transer.

Comment: That worked great!  I installed the module and then went into the sources configuration on the field_image.  Thanks!